# How to remove last TD in first LINE

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<table border="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td class="last">THIS SHOULD BE DELETED</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td class="last">NON DELETED</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td class="last">NON DELETED</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td class="last">NON DELETED</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vwa3p/

How to remove last TD in first LINE with CSS or jQuery?
Should be display: none, but how?

Comment: Jquery is fine, but always try to go for a CSS solution if possible. Read on my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jquery:

```
$('.last:first').remove();
```

With CSS:

```
table tbody tr:first-child td.last  {
    display:none
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

First line, meaning first row?

```
$('tr:first td:last').hide();
```

Comment: This will be pretty slow, searching the whole page instead of only in the tables isn't so good. Also if it was CSS it would be even slower since css is traversing from right to left...

Comment: It'll be slower, but arguably negligible for a single point operation. If the operation was something painstakingly repeated without variable caching, then that's a different call. The real benefit of putting a "`table`" context would be restricting the DOM search because, for example, you don't want to be hiding all the last `td`s in all the first `tr`s in all the `table`s in the document.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove it use:

```
$("table tr:first > td:last").remove();​
```

If you need to hide it use:

```
$("table tr:first > td:last").hide();​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vwa3p/1/

Answer (score 1):

css only:

```
​table tr:first-child td:last-child{
    display:none;
}​
```

or

```
​table tr:first-child .last{
    display:none;
}​
```

Comment: As commented earlier css is searching right to left, that means that it will first search the whole page for every td:last-child, the looks for every last td in every tr (will not stop until whole document has been searched). Then at last, is it in a table? Smarter would be

table > tbody > tr > td:last-child

Comment: @tbleckert 1. I know how CSS works. 2. sure you can do some optimizations but that was not part of the question. i simply showed a working solution. No reason to downvote imo... 3. in a somewhat normal document this won't be noticable anyways.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. But I'm starting to get really annoyed with the users here. You ain't helping anyone with just a "working" solution, teaching and explaining is at least as important as the solution itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table > tbody > tr:first > td:last').hide()
```

With CSS like this:

```
table > tbody > tr:first-child > td:last-child
```

I suggest using the child selector (>) for faster traversing and limiting it to only search in tbody, you never know if you later ads thead and/or tfooter.

Comment: -1 You really should not encourage users to rely on javascripts broken auto-insertion of `;`. I'm starting to get really annoyed with that.

Comment: Haha and you are, like 5 years old? Oh ok...and there's no reason of using ; on one line of code :) Same thing with css, last rule does not have to have a ;

Comment: Well, i could prove you wrong on your statement, but I leave this as howework to you to figure out.

Comment: Hah, please do. This will be interesting

Comment: The reason why we use semicolons in js is first, because we can't depend on the browser to understand our purpose, second the code will break if you use a compressor. Tell me how any of those two will handle one line of code wrong.

Comment: An exhaustive is not possible here. Basically the js-engine automatically inserts semicolons everywhere where you omit them. This can lead to hard to debug bugs due to the engine misinterpreting your code. Thats why it's a real bad habit to omit the semicolons or encourage others to do so. You can google the rest if you are interested;)

Comment: It's ONE line of code, when I say nothing, I mean that nothing can go wrong. You are basically saying exactly what I said, I just said that one line of code doesn't have to have a semicolon.

Comment: It's just a basic principle thing. The performance of the css-selector won't matter in 99% of the cases as does omitting the `;`.

Comment: Ok lets stop here, we have different opinions. If you want to discuss more, let's do it in the chat.